# Python - Static Class Variables

Tags: python, class, static

I'm from a C++ background and have often been using static vars to reduce the number of time variables have to be initialized (especially if the initialization takes very long). So from other posts on StackOverflow, people suggested using static class variables as follows:

```
class MyClass(object):

    StaticList1 = [...] # Very large list
    StaticList2 = [...] # Very large list
```

Now this is fine if there exists at least 1 instance of MyClass throughout the execution of the program and the lists are only created once. However, if at some stage of the execution there is no instance of MyClass, Python seems to remove the static lists (I assume because the reference counter drops to 0).

So my question, is there any easy way without using external modules to initialize StaticList1 and StaticList2 only once (the first time they are used) and never to remove them even if there is no instance of MyClass until the program exists (or you delete the lists manually)?

EDIT:

Maybe I oversimplified this issue. What I'm doing:

```
class MyClass(object):

    StaticList = None

    def __init__(self, info):
        if self.StaticList == None:
            print "Initializing ..."
            self.StaticList = []
            # Computationally expensive task to add elements to self.StaticList, depending on the value of parameter info

    def data(self):
        return self.StaticList
```

I import the module from another script and have a loop like this:

```
import myclass
for i in range(10000):
    m = myclass.MyClass(i)
    d = m.data()
    # Do something with d.
```

The initializing of the static list takes about 200 - 300 ms and is executed on every iteration of the loop, so the loop takes extremely long to finish.

Comment: You could take advantage of the fact that modules are singletons, so if you make these module level members they will always exist as long as the module is imported and will only exist once.

Comment: That doesnt sound right, I would not expect those lists to ever go anywhere. 

You are saying you are calling `MyClass.StaticList1 ...` and you are getting an error? What error are you getting?

Comment: * However, if at some stage of the execution there is no instance of MyClass, Python seems to remove the static lists* AFAIK, this is wrong. the class will exist independantly of the objects of that class, and all attributes defined at class level will continue to exist through the class. Can you show an example of your problem?

Comment: If every time a constructor/__init__ is called  a static variable is cleared and recalculated. Then I don't see why it should be static in C++ nor Python it is just work that needs to be done on every iteration of the loop. Probably most the of work occures  on the line `# Computationally expensive task...` and how you do that you don't show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your class does have a static field called `StaticList`, you are actually initializing and working with an *instance field* of the same name because of the `self` qualifier you are using. I think your code will work fine if you use `MyClass.StaticList` to initialize and access it instead.

In general, by Python's name lookup, you can access a class field via an instance as if it was an instance field (e.g., `self.StaticList`) on that instance *as long as* you haven't actually set an instance field of the same name on that instance. From that moment on, the instance field shadows the class field (i.e., `self.StaticList` will find your new value, while `MyClass.StaticList` will still refer to your class value).

As an example fresh from the interpreter:

```
>>> class A(object):
...  v=2      # static initialization
...
>>> A.v
2
>>> a=A()     # get an instance, and
>>> a.v       # get the static value via the instance:
2
>>> a.v = 7   # but now set 'v' on the instance, and ...
>>> a.v       # we will get the instance field's value:
7
>>> A.v       # the static value is still the old:
2
>>> b=A()     # and other instances of the class ...
>>> b.v       # will use the same old static value:
2
```

The instance variable `a.v` is initially equal to `A.v`, but by explicitly setting `a.v=7`, you are "dissociating" them in that instance.

While this means that, in principle, you *could* make use of a static class field `MyClass.Values` as well as an instance field `xyz.Values` of the same name, this is often discouraged for exactly this kind of confusion.

As a separate remark, you could consider annotating the `data` method as a `@staticmethod` (and remove the `self` argument in the move) and call it as `MyClass.data()` to make the fact clearer that you would be getting back the same list instance on every call.

Comment: That sounds logical if it was not for this: I've been using self.StaticVar for a bunch of other classes, where the static var is initialized directly at the declaration instead of the constructor. If I then print out self.StaticVar somewhere in the class, the value of the var is printed. Hence, in that case it seems MyClass.StaticVar is the same as self.StaticVar

Comment: I have extended the logic of the answer to address this aspect. :)